# Numpy import txt file as matrix without text lines

Tags: python, numpy

I have a txt file like the following, where I want to import the last column without the text so that I can do matrix vector operations with it

```
Node Number X Location (mm) Y Location (mm) Z Location (mm) Imported Initial Strain (mm/mm) 
1   54.545  29.798  7.3281  9.8534e-003 
2   53.976  28.979  7.2569  5.9253e-003 
3   68.579  16.26   7.3473  7.0993e-003 
4   67.902  16.955  7.3363  5.9801e-003
```

I tried `numpy.loadtxt("path")[1:,4]` but get the following error which I assume is due to the text inside my txt file

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Node'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy [loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) has a number of parameters:

- skiprows allows to skip the initial rows
- usecols allows to only load a selection of columns

Here what you want is:

```
arr = np.loadtxt(io.StringIO(t), skiprows=1, usecols=4)
```

With the sample data, it gives as expected:

```
array([0.0098534, 0.0059253, 0.0070993, 0.0059801])
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use [numpy.genfromtext](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) which allow ignoring starting line(s) with `skip_header`, so it your case:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.genfromtxt("file.txt", skip_header=1)
```

should create `numpy.ndarray` from data from `file.txt`. Beware that in older versions of NumPy there is `skiprows` rather than `skip_header` in `genfromtxt` function (see linked docs for details).